# Two font colors in one cell of java fx table

Tags: java, css, swing

I'm new to java so be kind. I know that in a jtable i can use html to style the cell contents and have two different font colors in one cell.

```
<span color:"red">red</span><span color:blue>blue</span>
```

Or something along those lines

Before I started my project in java swing i read up on java fx and was wondering if i should start there.

right now we use a excel spreadsheet to handle the data but would like to take it out of MS Office.

Just needed to know if possible with java fx or if i should stay with swing table for now.

any and all advice is welcome.

Thank You

Comment: It's possible with Swing, and I'm guessing that it's very likely possible with JavaFx as well (I don't use JavaFx and so can't say anything concrete about this tool). You will need to do your own work to research these two libraries to see which will work better for your purposes, but I wouldn't base it on this functionality but rather on overall functionality as it applies to your current project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If i can't do the two color font functionality then i won't be able to do the project. So right now it will be started with swing. Can't find any thing on the net that pertains to this particular problem. Thanks Again